# Create a Dictionary<int, List<int>> from a Linq query

Tags: c#, dictionary, linq-to-entities

I have a table in database as follows...

```
ID(INT)    Values(VARCHAR(50))  
1          200,300  
2          100  
3          400,500
```

when I query, I need to get this data in a Dictionary>

The code I have so far is...

`var x = (from o in Values
         select o).ToDictionary(o=>o.ID, p=>p.Values)`

I would like the `p.Values` to be converted to a List so I also need to perform a Convert.ToInt32() possibly!
Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
var x = 
(from o in Values select o)
.ToDictionary(o => o.ID, 
              p => p.Values.Split(',')
                    .Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x))
                    .ToList());
```

`.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x))` can be converted to a method group like this ;-) `.Select(Convert.ToInt32)`

Comment: p.Values is a string of comma delimited items!

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I implemented by using a split call after writing that comment to you! Marking it as answer! :-)